# How an Android native executable accept external socket connections?

Tags: android, c++, sockets, android-service, android-framework

I am working on developing an Android native executable service which is launched by init(I register it in init.rc) when system boots up. This native executable creates a socket listening on 0.0.0.0:4615 and is supposed to accept connections from outside.

OS is Android K; it runs on a development kit which has Ethernet interface for plugging it onto a Lan.

I have done the test running the same native executable in adb shell as root. It works fine - an external socket client on my Windows machine can connect to the native executable and send/recv message successfully. When I have it launched by init, it listens to 0.0.0.0:4615 successfully, but the external socket client cannot connect to it - connection refused.

The snippet I added in init.rc is:

```
service msger-daemon /system/bin/msgerd
    class main
```

When "ps" to check the user of msgerd, we found it was root.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't C POSIX sockets work regardless of the connection type?

Comment: Having a listening service on a phone can be problematic, because if it's not on a WIFI network you will not know beforehand what address it will get, or that the phone company will allow connections to arbitrary ports through their network.

Comment: Not on a phone, I am working on a development kit(a board) which supports Ethernet. And the test running the same executable in adb shell as root passes. I want to know how I could have it work when launched by init.

Comment: Maybe you can post your init.rc script about the service.

Comment: The snippet I added in init.rc is in the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding a SE policy file under $TOP/external/sepolicy, the content of that file is:

```
# File types must be defined for file_contexts.
type msgerd, domain;
type msgerd_exec, exec_type, file_type;

init_daemon_domain(msgerd)

permissive msgerd;

# Add msgerd to various domains
net_domain(msgerd)
allow msgerd self:capability { net_admin net_raw };
```

If anyone would like to review and advice, welcome!